# Best way to use reactions as buttons in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently working a bot that bans maps players can/cannot play in CSGO. On click of a reaction, I would want to push a certain map to an array titled bannedMaps. What is the best way to go about this? I have the reactions reacted to the prompt, and the array of objects for the map also done.

Answer (score 1):

A key point when working with reactions are emojis, when I wrote something similar once, I ended up encoding those emojis manually:

```
function inlineEmoji(name /*: string*/) {
 return ":" + name + ":";
}


const encoded/*: {[name: string]: string}*/ = {
  "zero":   "\u0030\u20E3",
  "one":    "\u0031\u20E3",
  "two":    "\u0032\u20E3",
  "three":  "\u0033\u20E3",
  "four":   "\u0034\u20E3",
  "five":   "\u0035\u20E3",
  "six":    "\u0036\u20E3",
  "seven":  "\u0037\u20E3",
  "eight":  "\u0038\u20E3",
  "nine":   "\u0039\u20E3",

   "ok_hand":  "\uD83D\uDC4C",
   "x":        "\u274C",
   "thumbdown": "\uD83D\uDC4E",
   "white_check_mark": "\u2705",
};

 function emoji(name /*: string*/) { return encoded[name]; } 

function isEmoji(emoji/*: string*/) {
 return (reaction/*: MessageReaction*/) => reaction.emoji.name === encoded[emoji];
}
```

Now the next thing we have to do is to track reactions:

```
 const onReaction /*: { [key: string]: (reaction: MessageReaction) => void| Promise<void> }*/ = {};

const client = new Client(); // your discord client

client.on("messageReactionAdd", reaction => {
  if(onReaction[reaction.message.id])
    onReaction[reaction.message.id](reaction);
});
```

Now it is quite straightforward to count reactions on a certain message:

```
// Waits for a reaction that is "emoji" and was clicked "count" times (excluding the bot), if "emoji" is empty, it will take the first emoji reaching the count
function waitForReaction(msg/*: Message*/, emoji/*: string */= "", count = 1)/*: Promise<MessageReaction>*/ {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  onReaction[msg.id] = function react(reaction/*: MessageReaction*/) {
    if(emoji && !isEmoji(emoji)(reaction))
      return;

    // Don't count the bot itself:
    if(reaction.count >= count + +reaction.me) {
      resolve(reaction);
    // Allow for GCing to prevent memory leaking:
      onReaction[msg.id] = undefined;
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Through that you can also easily do votings on questions:

```
// Waits for "min" users to vote for ðŸ‘Œ and against ðŸ‘Ž, then it indicates the state and returns with true âœ… or false âŒ
async function voteFor(previous/*: Message*/, question/*: string*/, min = 1)/*: Promise<{ status: boolean, voters: DiscordUser[] }>*/ {
 const message = await previous.reply(question) /*as Message*/;
 // Add "buttons" so that the user can vote
 await message.react(emoji('ok_hand'));
 await message.react(emoji('thumbdown'));

 // Let the two voter groups race, until one reaches the maximum
 const majority = await waitForReaction(message, undefined, min);


 // Check wether the majority was for or against
 const status = isEmoji('ok_hand')(majority);

  // indicate the state
  await message.react(status ? emoji('white_check_mark') : emoji('x'));

  return { status, voters: majority.users.array() };
}
```

To then be used as:

```
 const previous = someChannel.send("Vote for it:");
 const { status, voters } = await voteFor(previous, "Should I answer again?");
 if(status) previous.reply("Okay");
```